# How can I detect when an outlook Separate form region button is clicked

Tags: outlook-addin

I have a separate form region for new mail messages and I'd like to know how I can update the form data whenever the button is clicked to show it.

I am currently loading the form data on load but that only loads the data once and doesn't account for the user flipping back and forth between the new mail message and the separate form region.

What I'd like to do is to update the form data whenever the To email address changes but there doesn't seem to be any event hook available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

In the form region's constructor, listen to the current inspector's PageChange event:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().PageChange += new InspectorEvents_10_PageChangeEventHandler(CurrentInspector_PageChange);

void CurrentInspector_PageChange(ref string ActivePageName)
    {
        if (ActivePageName == "MySeparteForm")
        {
            //do work ...
        }
    }
```